# How to provide input to the screen reader in a Tk application?

Tags: tkinter, accessibility, tk-toolkit, gnome

I have a [Python+Tkinter application](https://thonny.org) to which I'd like to add some screen-reader support.

I'd like to make it work both in Windows and Linux, but I'll start with Linux. Unfortunately Tk doesn't provide required information to at-spi (see [here](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=0e294d9604) and [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-September/003480.html)).

I found [Tka11y](https://pypi.org/project/Tka11y/) based on [Papi](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/papi.html), but they haven't been updated for a while. When I tried a minimal example with my Python 2.7 I got core dump.

Do you know any  other options?

Can I somehow provide direct input to the screen reader without involving a widget toolkit at all? For example, can I send a text to narrate whenever the user moves from one line to another in the editor?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EthanField, why?

Comment: ["...they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)